# How to set URL direct donwloadable

Tags: php, html, web, hosting, cpanel

I have a short video sharing website. The user can download video from there. I'm facing some problem now. I want the user to download the video directly but when users visit my link browser auto-playing the video.

I only want when user click on link Video download will start auto.

**Now I'm sharing video link like this 
  Example: www.example.com/examle.mp4**

Please give me suggestion

Comment: If you are using bootstrap. there is a tag with download to direct download. 
eg:  <a href="YOUR_URL" download  >Download</a>

Comment: Its not only about bootstarp. I want my link direct downloadable. I can share my URL anywhere, when visitor click on my URL, then browser will start downloading the video. I dont want it to play online.

Comment: Not sure this needs any PHP involvement, as suggested in the two currently existing answers. Setting the Content-Type header should be enough for force a download, and that can be done in a RewriteRule directly, using the [`T` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for answering. I want my URL to make direct downloadable. You guys are suggesting me for php file but i found a solution online. This work.

I just need to put this code on `.htaccess`

```html
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|MP4)">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

This works perfectly.

Thank you Guys

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = "www.example.com/examle.mp4"; 

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . basename($file) . "'"); 

readfile ($file);
exit(); 
?>
```

Comment: Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of linking to the video file directly you could link to a php file which does trigger the download for you.

```
<?php
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=movie.mp4;');
  header('Content-Length: '. filesize('movie.mp4'));
  readfile('movie.mp4');
  exit;
```

With `.htaccess` you could redirect the mp4 link to your php file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^movie.mp4$ ./movie.php
```